# React native login to get user_id

Tags: android, react-native

https://reactnativecode.com/react-native-user-login-using-php-mysql/
I am following the above link to do a simple login app hence I would like to get the user_id after I login but fail, can someone please show me how to do it to display user_id after login?

Below is the code for php

```
<?php 
// Importing DBConfig.php file.
include 'DBConfig.php';

// Creating connection.
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 // Getting the received JSON into $json variable.
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

 // decoding the received JSON and store into $obj variable.
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);

// Populate User email from JSON $obj array and store into $email.
$email = $obj['email'];

// Populate Password from JSON $obj array and store into $password.
$password = $obj['password'];

//Applying User Login query with email and password match.
$Sql_Query = "select * from user where email = '$email' and password = '$password' ";

// Executing SQL Query.
$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query));


if(isset($check)){

 $SuccessLoginMsg = 'Data Matched';

 // Converting the message into JSON format.
$SuccessLoginJson = json_encode($SuccessLoginMsg);

// Echo the message.
 echo $SuccessLoginJson ; 

 }

 else{

 // If the record inserted successfully then show the message.
$InvalidMSG = 'Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again' ;

// Converting the message into JSON format.
$InvalidMSGJSon = json_encode($InvalidMSG);

// Echo the message.
 echo $InvalidMSGJSon ;

 }

 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And here is react native code which allow user login

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, Button, Text} from 'react-native';

// Importing Stack Navigator library to add multiple activities.
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// Creating Login Activity.
class LoginActivity extends Component {

  // Setting up Login Activity title.
  static navigationOptions =
   {
      title: 'LoginActivity',
   };

constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {

      UserEmail: '',
      UserPassword: ''

    }

  }

UserLoginFunction = () =>{

 const { UserEmail }  = this.state ;
 const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;


fetch('http://localhost/login/login.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({

    email: UserEmail,

    password: UserPassword

  })

}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        // If server response message same as Data Matched
       if(responseJson === 'Data Matched')
        {

            //Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', { Email: UserEmail });

        }
        else{

          Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });


  }

  render() {
    return (

<View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <Text style= {styles.TextComponentStyle}>User Login Form</Text>

        <TextInput

          // Adding hint in Text Input using Place holder.
          placeholder="Enter User Email"

          onChangeText={UserEmail => this.setState({UserEmail})}

          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
        />

        <TextInput

          // Adding hint in Text Input using Place holder.
          placeholder="Enter User Password"

          onChangeText={UserPassword => this.setState({UserPassword})}

          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}

          secureTextEntry={true}
        />

        <Button title="Click Here To Login" onPress={this.UserLoginFunction} color="#2196F3" />



</View>

    );
  }
}

// Creating Profile activity.
class ProfileActivity extends Component
{

  // Setting up profile activity title.
   static navigationOptions =
   {
      title: 'ProfileActivity',

   };


   render()
   {

     const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;

      return(
         <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>

            <Text style = {styles.TextComponentStyle}> { this.props.navigation.state.params.Email } </Text>

            <Button title="Click here to Logout" onPress={ () => goBack(null) } />

         </View>
      );
   }
}

export default MainProject = StackNavigator(
{
   First: { screen: LoginActivity },

   Second: { screen: ProfileActivity }

});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

MainContainer :{

justifyContent: 'center',
flex:1,
margin: 10,
},

TextInputStyleClass: {

textAlign: 'center',
marginBottom: 7,
height: 40,
borderWidth: 1,
// Set border Hex Color Code Here.
 borderColor: '#2196F3',

 // Set border Radius.
 borderRadius: 5 ,

},

 TextComponentStyle: {
   fontSize: 20,
  color: "#000",
  textAlign: 'center',
  marginBottom: 15
 }
});
```

Comment: Where does this "user_id" come from? Is it created and stored in the mySql database with the username and password? If so then you would have to add it to the response instead of just the yes or no for login correct.

Comment: yes, it is add to the mysql. You mean add to the response is it like this?      
'Data Matched'.$user_id